# Can't load oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver in groovysh?

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

I am trying to go through a [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pg01115/index.html) on GroovySQL. The database I need to connect to is an Oracle database. So I downloaded [ojdbc6.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) and put it in `~/.groovy/lib/`. If I put the following script in a .groovy file, I can do `groovy testScript.groovy` and it will succeed:

```
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
println(OracleDriver.getCompileTime())
```

When I try to do the same thing via `groovysh`, I get the following error:

```
Oct 25, 2011 10:14:14 AM oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver registerMBeans
WARNING: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean.
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission register)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:568)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.checkMBeanTrustPermission(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1824)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:310)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:482)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans(OracleDriver.java:342)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver$1.run(OracleDriver.java:199)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:195)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at groovysh_evaluate.class$(groovysh_evaluate)
    at groovysh_evaluate.$get$$class$oracle$jdbc$driver$OracleDriver(groovysh_evaluate)
    at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
    at groovysh_evaluate$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter$evaluate.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:153)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:114)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell$leftShift$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1053)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1053)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:66)
    at java_lang_Runnable$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.run(Groovysh.groovy:442)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.run(Groovysh.groovy:381)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Main.main(Main.groovy:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:130)
===> Fri_Jul_31_19:30:28_PDT_2009
```

How can I use the Oracle JDBC driver from within the Groovy shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the shell without a `SecurityManager` that doesn't allow to register new `MBeans` (that's what the exception says).

Look for `-Djava.security.manager` in the startup script of the Groovy shell or for `System.setSecurityManager()` in the source code.

Note that you're opening your system to all kinds of attacks if you do that.

OTOH, configuring a `SecurityManager` using the standard tools is so complicated that I'm pretty sure no one ever got it right for any non-trivial example, so the question is whether the pains from installing one outweigh the gain in security.

Comment: It looks like groovysh loads a security manager in its source code (http://git.codehaus.org/gitweb.cgi?p=groovy-git.git;a=blob;f=src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/tools/shell/Main.groovy;h=d1ac8c9f8886565fc00ac08d27aa3f5ed8169c5e;hb=HEAD#l127). I'll just do it the non-interactive way. Thank you.